# hp-uft software failed to install

Tags: hp-uft

I am trying to install Unified Functional Testing (UFT) trial version. I have downloaded the software, but when I tried to install, it failed and giving me the following error,

> Error reading file: c:\users\username\downloads\application name\bin

When I looked into explorer I was not able to find "bin" folder. Would someone please help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

These are my UFT 15.0.1 Install notes:

There are two approaches for installing and this work best for me.

Download the Setup.exe – Skip the DVD .zip!

[image: UFT Setup.exe install downloading]

Run the file extract to a folder near the root.

[image: Starting the installation process]

Set the extraction path to a temp folder.

I usually put mine on the D: drive as my C: space is becoming increasingly limited.

After the installation is complete UFT will ask you to restart your system.

It will then display a dialog with Status: Removing Shortcuts
[image: UFT Removing Shortcuts]

This can take up to 10 minutes to complete so be patient!

Once complete: Restart your computer a second time. (Very Important!)

Final Tip: I'm not sure UFT offers the option for an installation path.
If you need the space on the C: drive, I recommend after installation to creating a Symbolic Link from a larger drive and moving the files there, if possible.

When creating a new Project definitely put that on a large drive near the root.
The default path is really buried.